# Sys.UI.DomElement.getBounds

Tags: asp.net, ajax, jquery

I have an asp.net 4.0 web application I want to use Sys.UI.DomElement.getBounds to get panel's bounds. I have used following JQuery code:

var el = $get('#panel1');

var box = Sys.UI.DomElement.getBounds(el);

but I am getting error that Sys is not defined. Can you please tell me what are the pre requisites of using Sys.UI.DomElement.getBounds ?

Thanks,

Comment: When does that code run? The `Sys` object might not be available yet if it runs before `pageLoad()`.

Comment: It is javascript code and runs inside IFRame. A page is loaded in IFrame. and that page has this code

Comment: Does the page inside the `<iframe>` include the necessary scripts? Is that code located inside the `pageLoad()` function?

Comment: Yes, It has ajaxtoolkit scriptmanager included

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mixing ASP.NET AJAX with JQuery, change your code to:

```
var el = $get('<%= panel1.ClientID %>');

var box = Sys.UI.DomElement.getBounds(el);
```

I'm assuming panel1 is a server control, otherwise, just do $get('panel1'); if not.  You could also use JQuery's outerwidth and outerHeight or other methods found here: http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/ to get the size of an element.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

"Sys is undefined" will occur if the Microsoft Ajax JavaScript file(s) fail to load. Make sure this is not the case. To do so use Fiddler or Firebug and inspect your page for failing HTTP requests. Look for 404 and 500 HTTP codes.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I used

var el = $get('#panel1');

var box = Sys.UI.DomElement.getBounds(el[0]);

and it worked.